# get id value by index using name jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

**html**

```
<input id="1" name="myText" type="text" value="20"/>
<input id="2" name="myText" type="text" value="30"/>
<input id="3" name="myText" type="text" value="40"/>
```

How can I get id value by `index` using name?

The following code snippet is not working

```
var getVal = $('[name="myText"]').index(1);
```

Comment: You had a typo `vat` instead of `var`. And you better add the tagName to the selector.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

jQuery holds the DOM elements in the set like an array so you can use the indexes operator(`[]`) to get the element, or get the jQuery object that wraps the desired element with `:eq(n)` `.eq(n)`

```
$('input[name="myText"]:eq(1)').attr('id')
```

You should mention what to you consider to be `index(1)` the first or the second:

```
$('input[name="myText"]:eq(0)').attr('id') // First
$('input[name="myText"]:eq(1)').attr('id') // Second
```

Or:

```
$('input[name="myText"]')[0].id // First
```

Comment: index(1) means obviously second

Comment: @ShahidGhafoor. It's not that obvious, css selectors use the 1-base index... _"Note that since JavaScript arrays use 0-based indexing, these selectors reflect that fact. This is why $('.myclass:eq(1)') selects the second element in the document with the class myclass, rather than the first. In contrast, :nth-child(n) uses 1-based indexing to conform to the CSS specification."_

Comment: dear, but this is javascript(jquery) code. means  0-based indexing ;-)..kidding @gdoron

Answer (score 4):

If you want the first value, you can filter and use the `attr` method to get the value of the id attribute.

```
var getVal = $('[name="myText"]:first').attr('id'); // first id
```

If you want some other element, you can use `eq` and choose the zero-based element in the collection.

```
var getVal = $('[name="myText"]:eq(1)').attr('id'); // second id
```

Comment: He wants the second element, not the first.

Comment: @dunsmoreb. How can you tell?

Comment: @dunsmoreb that could be, but since he's also using `index` improperly it's not too much of a stretch to think he's also using 1-based indexing.  I've clarified just in case.

Answer (score 2):

My answer refers to accessing elements in the jQuery result object by index. You can use selectors such as [`:eq`](http://api.jquery.com/eq-selector/) indicated in other answers.

However, you can use [`.get(1)`](http://api.jquery.com/get/) instead of your `index`.

```
var id = $('[name="myText"]').get(1).id;
```

Is equivalent to

```
var id = $('[name="myText"]:eq(1)').attr('id');
```

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/HackedByChinese/UmKw6/1/

The second method is the preferred route, since it means you never leave the `jQuery` result object and thus can chain other jQuery calls in one statement.

```
var id = $('[name="myText"]:eq(1)').css('color', 'red').attr('id'); // example of chaining jQuery methods. sets the text color to red and then returns the id.
```

Comment: `get` returns a DOM element, not a jQuery object... You will get the error: `TypeError: Object a has no method 'attr'`

Comment: This answer is incorrect. The `.get()` function returns the actual DOM element, so you can't use the jQuery `.attr()` function on it. You'll just get a syntax error.

Comment: Works fine for me. See the fiddle I have attached.