# How can I get the count of ids who are using same name

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, asp.net-mvc

I am facing a problem such like, I can't extract the dependent `ids` who are belongs to same `name`.

Here is my HTML

```
<table id="table-data" class="table table-bordered table-data" style="vertical-align: middle;">
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <th style="width: 15%">Project</th>
            <th style="width: 15%">Module</th>
            <th style="width: 15%">Relevant Client</th>
            <th style="width: 20%">Task</th>
            <th style="width: 5%">Hours</th>
            <th style="width: 20%">Comments</th>
            <th></th>
        </tr>

        <tr id="1045">
            <input id="ChildId" name="ChildId" type="hidden" value="1045">
            <td>
                <select class="form-control input-sm valid" id="ProjectId0" name="ProjectId" onchange="iniatializeModuleClientAndTask(this)" onload="selecetTheTask(this)">
                    <option value="">--Select--</option>
                    <option selected="selected" value="1">Compliant Web</option>
                </select>
            </td>
            <td>
                <select class="form-control input-sm" id="ModuleId0" name="ModuleId">
                    <option value="">-Select-</option>
                </select>
            </td>
            <td>
                <select class="form-control input-sm" id="ClientId0" name="ClientId">
                    <option value="">-Select-</option>
                </select>
            </td>
            <td>
                <select class="form-control input-sm" id="TaskId0" name="TaskId">
                    <option value="">-Select-</option>
                </select>
            </td>
            <td>
                <input class="form-control input-sm" id="ExpendedHour" name="ExpendedHour" type="text" value="4">
            </td>
            <td>
                <input class="form-control input-sm" id="TaskComments" name="TaskComments" type="text" value="a">
            </td>
            <td>
                <a class="removeButton btn btn-sm btn-danger" style="padding:3px 0 3px 8px;"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></span></a>
                <a class="addButton btn btn-sm btn-primary" style="padding:3px 0 3px 8px;"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></span></a>
            </td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <input id="ChildId" name="ChildId" type="hidden" value="0">
            <td>
                <select class="form-control input-sm" id="ProjectId1" name="ProjectId" onchange="iniatializeModuleClientAndTask(this)">
                    <option value="">--Select--</option>
                    <option value="1">Compliant Web</option>
                </select>
            </td>
            <td>
                <select class="form-control input-sm" id="ModuleId1" name="ModuleId">
                    <option value="">-Select-</option>
                </select>
            </td>
            <td>
                <select class="form-control input-sm" id="ClientId1" name="ClientId">
                    <option value="">-Select-</option>
                </select>
            </td>
            <td>
                <select class="form-control input-sm" id="TaskId1" name="TaskId">
                    <option value="">-Select-</option>
                </select>
            </td>
            <td>
                <input class="form-control input-sm" id="ExpendedHour" name="ExpendedHour" type="text" value="">
            </td>
            <td>
                <input class="form-control input-sm" id="TaskComments" name="TaskComments" type="text" value="">
            </td>
            <td>
                <a class="removeButton btn btn-sm btn-danger" style="padding:3px 0 3px 8px;"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></span></a>
                <a class="addButton btn btn-sm btn-primary" style="padding:3px 0 3px 8px;"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></span></a>
            </td>

        </tr>

        <tr>
            <input id="ChildId" name="ChildId" type="hidden" value="0">
            <td>
                <select class="form-control input-sm" id="ProjectId2" name="ProjectId" onchange="iniatializeModuleClientAndTask(this)">
                    <option value="" id="ProjectId2">--Select--</option>
                    <option value="1">Compliant Web</option>
                </select>
            </td>
            <td>
                <select class="form-control input-sm" id="ModuleId2" name="ModuleId">
                    <option value="" id="ModuleId2">-Select-</option>
                </select>
            </td>
            <td>
                <select class="form-control input-sm" id="ClientId2" name="ClientId">
                    <option value="" id="ClientId2">-Select-</option>
                </select>
            </td>
            <td>
                <select class="form-control input-sm" id="TaskId2" name="TaskId">
                    <option value="" id="TaskId2">-Select-</option>
                </select>
            </td>
            <td>
                <input class="form-control input-sm" id="ExpendedHouNaN" name="ExpendedHour" type="text" value="">
            </td>
            <td>
                <input class="form-control input-sm" id="TaskCommentNaN" name="TaskComments" type="text" value="">
            </td>
            <td>
                <a class="removeButton btn btn-sm btn-danger" style="padding:3px 0 3px 8px;"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></span></a>
                <a class="addButton btn btn-sm btn-primary" style="padding:3px 0 3px 8px;"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></span></a>
            </td>

        </tr>
        <tr>
            <input id="ChildId" name="ChildId" type="hidden" value="0">
            <td>
                <select class="form-control input-sm" id="ProjectId3" name="ProjectId" onchange="iniatializeModuleClientAndTask(this)">
                    <option value="" id="ProjectId3">--Select--</option>
                    <option value="1">Compliant Web</option>
                </select>
            </td>
            <td>
                <select class="form-control input-sm" id="ModuleId3" name="ModuleId">
                    <option value="" id="ModuleId3">-Select-</option>
                </select>
            </td>
            <td>
                <select class="form-control input-sm" id="ClientId3" name="ClientId">
                    <option value="" id="ClientId3">-Select-</option>
                </select>
            </td>
            <td>
                <select class="form-control input-sm" id="TaskId3" name="TaskId">
                    <option value="" id="TaskId3">-Select-</option>
                </select>
            </td>
            <td>
                <input class="form-control input-sm" id="ExpendedHouNaNaN" name="ExpendedHour" type="text" value="">
            </td>
            <td>
                <input class="form-control input-sm" id="TaskCommentNaNaN" name="TaskComments" type="text" value="">
            </td>
            <td>
                <a class="removeButton btn btn-sm btn-danger" style="padding:3px 0 3px 8px;"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></span></a>
                <a class="addButton btn btn-sm btn-primary" style="padding:3px 0 3px 8px;"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></span></a>
            </td>

        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Look here on my HTML code I have same name like `ProjectId`, `ModuleId`, `TaskId` and so many. Actually the number of table rows are propagating dynamically. So the ids are different from the name. I have done this because in `MVC4` I can easily get those data by name in `POST` action. But I badly need to do some work on view page. So I want to count how many ids are using the same class name. I want to apply some business on those classes.

I have gone through this [Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10964378/get-id-value-by-index-using-name-jquery), it's quiet similar to me with a particular different. There he/she shows the ids and my difference is I want to `count` them. I have found also another solution [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3253775/css-class-and-id-with-the-same-name), however it's done in `CSS` Badly I need it in `Javascript` or `jQuery`

Moreover the number of the `ids` can be as much as possible and may not be in sequence like `ProjectId1`, `ProjectId2`, then `projectId99` but each of them will be under `ProjectId` class. therefore I want to get the total number ids by it's `name`. Thank you.

Comment: Just so you are aware... duplicate IDs are invalid in HTML and will cause issues.

Comment: Your HTML is invalid. `id` values **must** be unique in the document, you can't use the same `id` on more than one element. So that's the first thing to change. You might consider using `class` instead.

Comment: I'm not duplicating the ids. I am providing the same `name` only. All `ids` are totally different. Sorry to say that it's working fine, and there is no problem. And I am getting the data easily in Controller, through the name.

Comment: Your html makes no sense, particularly is your dynamically adding new items and will never correctly 2-way bind to any model. Suggest your look at [this article](http://haacked.com/archive/2008/10/23/model-binding-to-a-list.aspx/) to understand how to bind correctly to collections, and the answers [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28019793/submit-same-partial-view-called-multiple-times-data-to-controller/28081308#28081308) and [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40539321/a-partial-view-passing-a-collection-using-the-html-begincollectionitem-helper/40541892#40541892) for examples

Comment: @ [Stephen Muecke](http://stackoverflow.com/users/3559349/stephen-muecke) I can't do that. on my model the input fields are coming from a child model [look](http://imgur.com/a/PNHIf), here child models are unlimited. It will be generate from the `+` button, SO there is no limit.  look the  [razor](http://imgur.com/a/NGDhj), if you can give me a better suggestion on `razor`, i mean to modify it, then it will be perfect.

Comment: @AnandaM.Ghosh, Did you even bother to read the links I gave you? That's exactly what the code does! It generates a new objects for your collection property in the view and gives it the correct name attributes for binding to your model, along with validation etc (which your code will never do!). And if you want to add 1 million items to the collection, just click the '+' button 1 million times

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have got a few elements belonging to the same name, then you can simply use the `length` or `size()` of jQuery to find the number of selected elements. See the [Documentation](https://api.jquery.com/length/) for details.

So , the following should return the number of elements with a name attribute 'projectId'

```
$('[name=projectId]').length;
```

> The number of elements currently matched. The .size() method will return the same value.

Furthermore, if you need count of all elements with `name=projectId` and an Id starting with `ProjectId`(ProjectId1, ProjectId2 ... and so on) then you can use the ["Attribute starts with selector"](https://api.jquery.com/attribute-starts-with-selector/) as well like below :

```
$('[id^=Projectid][name=projectId]').length;
```

Or, all elements which have at least an id :

```
$('[id][name=projectId]').length;
```

```js
$('#Res').text("Number of Elemnts in with name 'projectId' : " +$('[name=projectId]').length);

$('#Res1').text("Number of Elemnts in with name 'projectId' and Id starting with 'test': " +$('[id^=test][name=projectId]').length);

$('#Res2').text("Number of Elemnts in with name 'projectId' and containing an Id : " +$('[id][name=projectId]').length);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="test" name="projectId"></div>
<div id="test1" name="projectId"></div>
<div id="test2" name="projectId"></div>
<div id="test3" name="projectId"></div>
<div id="anyId" name="projectId"></div>
<div name="projectId"></div>
<div id="Res"></div>
<div id="Res1"></div>
<div id="Res2"></div>
```

Comment: Sorry to say that you have used the `class` here, But I have asked for using the `name`. Please recheck you answer.

Comment: Fixed as per your need ... Look at [Jquery Attribute Selectors](https://api.jquery.com/attribute-equals-selector/) Documentation for better understanding.

Comment: `<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="test" name="projectId"></div>
<div id="test1" name="projectId"></div>
<div id="test2" name="projectId"></div>
<div id="test3" name="projectId"></div>
<div name="projectId"></div>` try for this, it will come 5, but actually it will return 4. Because only 4 `ids` are belongs to this `name`

Comment: I have added additional selectors to my response code snippet ... check it out !

Comment: @AnandaM.Ghosh : If this answers your query, please mark it as an answer.

Comment: Yes!!!!! That's what I am searching for. Cheers. If my question is unique then put a positive grace on it. ^

Answer (score 0):

Non-jquery method:

I'd recommend using `document.querySelectorAll`.

The following is an example where I get elements by their names: `ModuleId`, `ProjectId` and `ClientId`.

```js
var names = ["ProjectId", "ModuleId", "ClientId"]

for (let i = 0; i < names.length; i++)
{
  let temp = names[i];
  let things = document.querySelectorAll(`[name="${temp}"]`);
  console.log(temp, "count:", things.length);
}
```

```html
<table id="table-data" class="table table-bordered table-data" style="vertical-align: middle;">
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <th style="width: 15%">Project</th>
            <th style="width: 15%">Module</th>
            <th style="width: 15%">Relevant Client</th>
            <th style="width: 20%">Task</th>
            <th style="width: 5%">Hours</th>
            <th style="width: 20%">Comments</th>
            <th></th>
        </tr>

        <tr id="1045">
            <input id="ChildId" name="ChildId" type="hidden" value="1045">
            <td>
                <select class="form-control input-sm valid" id="ProjectId0" name="ProjectId" onchange="iniatializeModuleClientAndTask(this)" onload="selecetTheTask(this)">
                    <option value="">--Select--</option>
                    <option selected="selected" value="1">Compliant Web</option>
                </select>
            </td>
            <td>
                <select class="form-control input-sm" id="ModuleId0" name="ModuleId">
                    <option value="">-Select-</option>
                </select>
            </td>
            <td>
                <select class="form-control input-sm" id="ClientId0" name="ClientId">
                    <option value="">-Select-</option>
                </select>
            </td>
            <td>
                <select class="form-control input-sm" id="TaskId0" name="TaskId">
                    <option value="">-Select-</option>
                </select>
            </td>
            <td>
                <input class="form-control input-sm" id="ExpendedHour" name="ExpendedHour" type="text" value="4">
            </td>
            <td>
                <input class="form-control input-sm" id="TaskComments" name="TaskComments" type="text" value="a">
            </td>
            <td>
                <a class="removeButton btn btn-sm btn-danger" style="padding:3px 0 3px 8px;"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></span></a>
                <a class="addButton btn btn-sm btn-primary" style="padding:3px 0 3px 8px;"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></span></a>
            </td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <input id="ChildId" name="ChildId" type="hidden" value="0">
            <td>
                <select class="form-control input-sm" id="ProjectId1" name="ProjectId" onchange="iniatializeModuleClientAndTask(this)">
                    <option value="">--Select--</option>
                    <option value="1">Compliant Web</option>
                </select>
            </td>
            <td>
                <select class="form-control input-sm" id="ModuleId1" name="ModuleId">
                    <option value="">-Select-</option>
                </select>
            </td>
            <td>
                <select class="form-control input-sm" id="ClientId1" name="ClientId">
                    <option value="">-Select-</option>
                </select>
            </td>
            <td>
                <select class="form-control input-sm" id="TaskId1" name="TaskId">
                    <option value="">-Select-</option>
                </select>
            </td>
            <td>
                <input class="form-control input-sm" id="ExpendedHour" name="ExpendedHour" type="text" value="">
            </td>
            <td>
                <input class="form-control input-sm" id="TaskComments" name="TaskComments" type="text" value="">
            </td>
            <td>
                <a class="removeButton btn btn-sm btn-danger" style="padding:3px 0 3px 8px;"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></span></a>
                <a class="addButton btn btn-sm btn-primary" style="padding:3px 0 3px 8px;"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></span></a>
            </td>

        </tr>

        <tr>
            <input id="ChildId" name="ChildId" type="hidden" value="0">
            <td>
                <select class="form-control input-sm" id="ProjectId2" name="ProjectId" onchange="iniatializeModuleClientAndTask(this)">
                    <option value="" id="ProjectId2">--Select--</option>
                    <option value="1">Compliant Web</option>
                </select>
            </td>
            <td>
                <select class="form-control input-sm" id="ModuleId2" name="ModuleId">
                    <option value="" id="ModuleId2">-Select-</option>
                </select>
            </td>
            <td>
                <select class="form-control input-sm" id="ClientId2" name="ClientId">
                    <option value="" id="ClientId2">-Select-</option>
                </select>
            </td>
            <td>
                <select class="form-control input-sm" id="TaskId2" name="TaskId">
                    <option value="" id="TaskId2">-Select-</option>
                </select>
            </td>
            <td>
                <input class="form-control input-sm" id="ExpendedHouNaN" name="ExpendedHour" type="text" value="">
            </td>
            <td>
                <input class="form-control input-sm" id="TaskCommentNaN" name="TaskComments" type="text" value="">
            </td>
            <td>
                <a class="removeButton btn btn-sm btn-danger" style="padding:3px 0 3px 8px;"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></span></a>
                <a class="addButton btn btn-sm btn-primary" style="padding:3px 0 3px 8px;"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></span></a>
            </td>

        </tr>
        <tr>
            <input id="ChildId" name="ChildId" type="hidden" value="0">
            <td>
                <select class="form-control input-sm" id="ProjectId3" name="ProjectId" onchange="iniatializeModuleClientAndTask(this)">
                    <option value="" id="ProjectId3">--Select--</option>
                    <option value="1">Compliant Web</option>
                </select>
            </td>
            <td>
                <select class="form-control input-sm" id="ModuleId3" name="ModuleId">
                    <option value="" id="ModuleId3">-Select-</option>
                </select>
            </td>
            <td>
                <select class="form-control input-sm" id="ClientId3" name="ClientId">
                    <option value="" id="ClientId3">-Select-</option>
                </select>
            </td>
            <td>
                <select class="form-control input-sm" id="TaskId3" name="TaskId">
                    <option value="" id="TaskId3">-Select-</option>
                </select>
            </td>
            <td>
                <input class="form-control input-sm" id="ExpendedHouNaNaN" name="ExpendedHour" type="text" value="">
            </td>
            <td>
                <input class="form-control input-sm" id="TaskCommentNaNaN" name="TaskComments" type="text" value="">
            </td>
            <td>
                <a class="removeButton btn btn-sm btn-danger" style="padding:3px 0 3px 8px;"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></span></a>
                <a class="addButton btn btn-sm btn-primary" style="padding:3px 0 3px 8px;"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></span></a>
            </td>

        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: OP wishes to count elements and not select them ... at least as per the question so far.

Comment: Then he can just add a `length` to it instead. Makes very little difference to the code.

Answer (score 0):

You can find all ids in all rows or specific row like this 
$('tr + tr [name=ProjectId]').length

```js
$('#ProjectIdResult').text("ProjectID in all rows: "+$('tr + tr [name=ProjectId]').length);
$('#ModuleIdResult').text("ModuleID in all rows: "+$('tr + tr [name=ModuleId]').length);
$('#TaskIdResult').text("TaskID in all rows: "+$('tr + tr [name=TaskId]').length);
$('#ClientIdResult').text("ClientID in all rows: "+$('tr + tr [name=ClientId]').length);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="table-data" class="table table-bordered table-data" style="vertical-align: middle;">
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <th style="width: 15%">Project</th>
            <th style="width: 15%">Module</th>
            <th style="width: 15%">Relevant Client</th>
            <th style="width: 20%">Task</th>
            <th style="width: 5%">Hours</th>
            <th style="width: 20%">Comments</th>
            <th></th>
        </tr>

        <tr id="1045">
            <input id="ChildId" name="ChildId" type="hidden" value="1045">
            <td>
                <select class="form-control input-sm valid" id="ProjectId0" name="ProjectId" onchange="iniatializeModuleClientAndTask(this)" onload="selecetTheTask(this)">
                    <option value="">--Select--</option>
                    <option selected="selected" value="1">Compliant Web</option>
                </select>
            </td>
            <td>
                <select class="form-control input-sm" id="ModuleId0" name="ModuleId">
                    <option value="">-Select-</option>
                </select>
            </td>
            <td>
                <select class="form-control input-sm" id="ClientId0" name="ClientId">
                    <option value="">-Select-</option>
                </select>
            </td>
            <td>
                <select class="form-control input-sm" id="TaskId0" name="TaskId">
                    <option value="">-Select-</option>
                </select>
            </td>
            <td>
                <input class="form-control input-sm" id="ExpendedHour" name="ExpendedHour" type="text" value="4">
            </td>
            <td>
                <input class="form-control input-sm" id="TaskComments" name="TaskComments" type="text" value="a">
            </td>
            <td>
                <a class="removeButton btn btn-sm btn-danger" style="padding:3px 0 3px 8px;"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></span></a>
                <a class="addButton btn btn-sm btn-primary" style="padding:3px 0 3px 8px;"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></span></a>
            </td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <input id="ChildId" name="ChildId" type="hidden" value="0">
            <td>
                <select class="form-control input-sm" id="ProjectId1" name="ProjectId" onchange="iniatializeModuleClientAndTask(this)">
                    <option value="">--Select--</option>
                    <option value="1">Compliant Web</option>
                </select>
            </td>
            <td>
                <select class="form-control input-sm" id="ModuleId1" name="ModuleId">
                    <option value="">-Select-</option>
                </select>
            </td>
            <td>
                <select class="form-control input-sm" id="ClientId1" name="ClientId">
                    <option value="">-Select-</option>
                </select>
            </td>
            <td>
                <select class="form-control input-sm" id="TaskId1" name="TaskId">
                    <option value="">-Select-</option>
                </select>
            </td>
            <td>
                <input class="form-control input-sm" id="ExpendedHour" name="ExpendedHour" type="text" value="">
            </td>
            <td>
                <input class="form-control input-sm" id="TaskComments" name="TaskComments" type="text" value="">
            </td>
            <td>
                <a class="removeButton btn btn-sm btn-danger" style="padding:3px 0 3px 8px;"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></span></a>
                <a class="addButton btn btn-sm btn-primary" style="padding:3px 0 3px 8px;"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></span></a>
            </td>

        </tr>

        <tr>
            <input id="ChildId" name="ChildId" type="hidden" value="0">
            <td>
                <select class="form-control input-sm" id="ProjectId2" name="ProjectId" onchange="iniatializeModuleClientAndTask(this)">
                    <option value="" id="ProjectId2">--Select--</option>
                    <option value="1">Compliant Web</option>
                </select>
            </td>
            <td>
                <select class="form-control input-sm" id="ModuleId2" name="ModuleId">
                    <option value="" id="ModuleId2">-Select-</option>
                </select>
            </td>
            <td>
                <select class="form-control input-sm" id="ClientId2" name="ClientId">
                    <option value="" id="ClientId2">-Select-</option>
                </select>
            </td>
            <td>
                <select class="form-control input-sm" id="TaskId2" name="TaskId">
                    <option value="" id="TaskId2">-Select-</option>
                </select>
            </td>
            <td>
                <input class="form-control input-sm" id="ExpendedHouNaN" name="ExpendedHour" type="text" value="">
            </td>
            <td>
                <input class="form-control input-sm" id="TaskCommentNaN" name="TaskComments" type="text" value="">
            </td>
            <td>
                <a class="removeButton btn btn-sm btn-danger" style="padding:3px 0 3px 8px;"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></span></a>
                <a class="addButton btn btn-sm btn-primary" style="padding:3px 0 3px 8px;"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></span></a>
            </td>

        </tr>
        <tr>
            <input id="ChildId" name="ChildId" type="hidden" value="0">
            <td>
                <select class="form-control input-sm" id="ProjectId3" name="ProjectId" onchange="iniatializeModuleClientAndTask(this)">
                    <option value="" id="ProjectId3">--Select--</option>
                    <option value="1">Compliant Web</option>
                </select>
            </td>
            <td>
                <select class="form-control input-sm" id="ModuleId3" name="ModuleId">
                    <option value="" id="ModuleId3">-Select-</option>
                </select>
            </td>
            <td>
                <select class="form-control input-sm" id="ClientId3" name="ClientId">
                    <option value="" id="ClientId3">-Select-</option>
                </select>
            </td>
            <td>
                <select class="form-control input-sm" id="TaskId3" name="TaskId">
                    <option value="" id="TaskId3">-Select-</option>
                </select>
            </td>
            <td>
                <input class="form-control input-sm" id="ExpendedHouNaNaN" name="ExpendedHour" type="text" value="">
            </td>
            <td>
                <input class="form-control input-sm" id="TaskCommentNaNaN" name="TaskComments" type="text" value="">
            </td>
            <td>
                <a class="removeButton btn btn-sm btn-danger" style="padding:3px 0 3px 8px;"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></span></a>
                <a class="addButton btn btn-sm btn-primary" style="padding:3px 0 3px 8px;"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></span></a>
            </td>

        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>

<div id="ProjectIdResult">
</div>
<div id="ModuleIdResult">
</div>
<div id="TaskIdResult">
</div>
<div id="ClientIdResult">
</div>
```